Error installing Ultralytics to run yolov5 on Raspberry Pi 3B with Bullseye, "Error: could not build wheels for opencv-python which use PEP 517..."
I am trying to install Ultralytics using pip on my Raspberry Pi 3B with Bullseye OS. While I was able to install all the dependencies to run yolov5 successfully, when trying to install Ultralytics. I get the error,
"Problem with CMake installation, aborting build. CMake executable is /tmp/pip-build-env-3didr32b/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cmake/data/bin/cmake

Error: Failed building wheel for opencv-python
Failed to build opencv-python
Error: could not build wheels for opencv-python which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly"

While there are ways to install opencv successfully and have worked for me, installing Ultralytics immediately makes it install opencv all over again, resulting in the same failure. Does anybody know how to fix this?
I have tried installing open-cv separately, and then installing ultralytics, but got the same error. Some suggested installing opencv-python-headless before installing ultralytics, but I was unable to successfully install this package.

Try this https://lindevs.com/install-precompiled-opencv-on-raspberry-pi/ without complied.
